# Meteor - update template data from jquery-ui draggable "start" event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, meteor

I have a collection of elements that can be moved. I sort the collection by the time they last got moved.

```
Cards.find({},{sort:{moved:1}});
```

When I start dragging an element I want to update the `moved` attribute, but I don't want to update the database before I'm done dragging.

This is my attempt:

```
Template.cardItem.rendered = function() {
    $('.card-item').draggable({
        handle: '.card-handle',
        start: function(evt, ui) {
            var data = Blaze.getData(evt.target);
            data.moved = new Date().getTime(); // not working
        },
        stop: function(evt, ui) {
            var card = {
                _id: $(this).attr('id'),
                left: ui.position.left,
                top: ui.position.top
            };
            Meteor.call('cardMove', card, function(error, result) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
    })
};
```

I guess my problem is that I don't know how to access the template instance from a jQuery context.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use: `Template.currentData()`

Maybe you're right about the not being able to get data from a jQuery context, I'm not sure about it also.

This is a perfect scenario to use Session or custom ReactiveDict, see the [documentation](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict).

You can also do:

```
this.autorun(function(computation){
    var data = Template.currentData(); //this is a reactive dependency
    if(computation.firstRun){
        //init your jquery code
    }
});
```

And you access data in your jQuery code. The reason why you need to create an autorun and check for the first run is to avoid running the jQuery code every time the data changes. I had severe performance issue when I was using `Template.rendered` to create widgets.

In your case, I think that using Session/ReactiveDict is the way to go. It gives more flexibility on the long run.

Note:
I don't like the Meteor method approach, I think it's against Meteor workflow. It would be simpler to use the `allow/deny` rules and directly insert it via `minimongo`.

Comment: What is `this` and `computation` in your code example, and where should it be put?

Comment: `this` point to current Template, example: `this.$` means that you're running jQuery only on this Template. This is a good practice. The `computation` is an argument that allows to access the computation. I'm using the `firstRun` property to check if this is the first that I'm running the `autorun`.